# Javascript syntax on function

Tags: javascript, function, syntax

Can you refer to function as array in javascript?
In the code below, function factorial is treated as an array..

```
function factorial(n) {
  if (isFinite(n) && n>0 && n==Math.round(n)) { 
    if (!(n in factorial))
      factorial[n] = n * factorial(n-1);
    return factorial[n];
  }
  else 
    return NaN;
}

factorial[1] = 1;
```

Answer (score 5):

Functions are objects. They can have properties (and have [a number by default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype)).

You usually can't treat them as arrays (since they don't have `Array` on their prototype chain and are missing most of the methods that arrays have) but `['property name']` is a general [way to access properties](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.1) and is not array specific.

Comment: So, does function factorial have 1 as its property? Property can be accessed by using "functionName.property", but "factorial.1" clearly violates the rule...Thanks for clarification in advance.

Comment: @user3562812 — Yes. If you use dot notation to access a property then the property name has to be an identifier. Identifiers cannot start with a number. Bracket notation allows access to a much wider range of property names.

Answer (score 0):

the functions can not be arrays, they could have properties .

```
function factorial(n){
    if(n == 1)
        return 1;

    return (n * factorial(n - 1) );
}
```